# WebApi controller isn't found

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have an example controller in my WebApi-project:

```
public class MilestonesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/milestones
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "M#1", "M#2" };
    }

    // GET api/milestones/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "M with {id}";
    }

    // POST api/milestones
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/milestones/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/milestones/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

If I try to navigate to it:

http://localhost:59493/api/milestones

I always get the error:

```
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:59493/api/milestones'.

No type was found that matches the controller named 'milestones'.
```

Thank you in advance!

Edit:

my WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Global.asax:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

Possible Solution:

I have deleted my project and I've created a new one (WebAPi project) and now it works. The WebApiConfig etc was the same, so I don't really know what was wrong with my first try

Comment: Could you add App_Start() method from Global.asax.cs too?

Comment: Missing web-api routes when the WebApiConfig exists is normally because they aren't wired up in the App_Start() (or some other method).  If you add a web api to an existing mvc app, then WebApiConfig is added, but not wired up.  Hence the request for App_Start

Comment: Try to comment out either `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);` or `WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);`

Comment: I have commented it out wihtout any success -.-

Answer (score 0):

you're missing the 'api' section of the url from your route. Try something more like;

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at where you created that controller. Maybe it is not in the Controllers folder, different namespace or that controller class is nested into another class

Comment: It doesn't work for me. The WebApi project has added this class for me

Comment: @GrayFox So, you should have that configuration already, can you post it your WebApiConfig and App_Start() ?

Comment: @GrayFox, can you look at your controller once more as in the post?